# Android: How to apply Material Desing animations on apps based on API version lower than L? Like Chrome, PlayStore, Youtube...

Tags: android, api, material-design

I'm working on an app that uses the version 14 of Android API. Now I'd like to implement new Material Design animations as do the Google Chrome, Playstore and Youtube apps  on many other versions of Android lower than L.

Where can I find some examples? 
How can I use the material design with versions of the API lower than L?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Google has not yet released a support library to do so. You will be able to do this in the V7 support library according to Google; however, there is no release date set.

The animations for material design can be done manually, albeit they are very tedious to do this way. For instance, the spinning icons shown use AnticipateOvershootInterpolator with the RotateAnimation.

The best you can do is follow their guidelines here:
http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html

Just follow their philosophy of design and when the support library comes out, implement it into your application.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best examples of Material Design *in the wild* is the [Google IO 2014](https://github.com/google/iosched) app. From the project description:

> This project is the Android app for the conference. The app supports devices running Android 4.0+, and is optimized for phones and tablets of all shapes and sizes. It also contains an Android Wear integration.
>
> We have updated the I/O app with material design and the Android L Developer Preview! For a quick preview of the new tactile surfaces, animated touch feedback, bold use of color, and refreshed iconography by checking out this teaser video or download the preview APK below.

For more on implementing these patterns/design checkout the [Android-L preview docs](http://developer.android.com/preview/material/index.html) :

> To use material design in your Android apps, follow the guidelines defined in the [material design specification](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) and use the new components and functionality available in the Android L Developer Preview.